# Better way to do UILabel animations in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-animation, uilabel

In the past, when I've wanted to do a nice fade animation from one UILabel text to another, I chuck in the following:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fade" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
myLabel.alpha = 0.0;
myLabel.text = @"Different string";
myLabel.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

As you can probably tell, the label does a quick fade out, change content, then fades back in.

I've seen some instances in other apps where the text just seems to fade really smoothly - without appearing to fade out and back in quickly.

Is it just me or is there a better way of achieving this?

Thanks.
Ricky.

Comment: not to pester, but did my answer ...answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps.

```
    -(void)showButton:(UIButton *)button {
        CABasicAnimation *opacityAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        opacityAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
        opacityAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];

        button.hidden = NO;

        [button.layer addAnimation:opacityAnimation 
                            forKey:@"opacity"];
    }

    -(void)hideButton:(UIButton *)button {

        CABasicAnimation *opacityAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        opacityAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
        opacityAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
        button.hidden = YES;

        [button.layer addAnimation:opacityAnimation 
                            forKey:@"opacity"];
    }
```